# How to sort a group of cells alphabetically - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In a single column I have multiple groups I would like to sort alphabetically like so:

[image: Two groups of cells to sort in a single column]

How can I sort Group 1 and Group 2 alphabetically without mixing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be much easier than I was expecting. Selecting the cells in the group then going to **Data** > **Sort range by column A, A -> Z** did what I wanted it to do.